# How to extract data from BMP image using metada-extractor

Tags: java, bmp, metadata-extractor

I am trying to extract metadata from a BMP image format using metadata-extractor, but it throws an exception that file type is not supported.

Metadata-extractor:https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor.git

My code:

```
public class MetaDataExtractor {

private Metadata metadata = null;

public Metadata extractMetadata() {
try {
        File file = new File("w3c_home.bmp");

        metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
    } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return metadata;
}
```

It returns this exception on the console:
com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:128)
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:95)
    at MetaDataExtractor.extractMetadata(MetaDataExtractor.java:16)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)

Comment: It seems that you are not using the latest version, the message ` File format is not supported` has been removed  on Mar 15, 2017. Try with the latest version.

Comment: @PranavBhatia did that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did....!